# What are the capabilities of Panda3D?

Tags: panda3d

1. Can Panda3D game be served from cloud such as AWS ?
2. Can Panda3D be used for mobile game development (iOS, Android) ? I'm aware Unity can be used but what about Panda3D ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Can the game be served from a cloud"? That can mean a lot of things, from just hosting a downloadable file over having a miltiplayer server run on AWS which your clients communicate with to streaming the full game from a server (in the style of Google Stadia). Please specify what scenario in particular you have in mind.

Comment: What I mean is can Panda3D game be a cloud game ? In a sense that is streamed from virtual servers on AWS and played on laptops or desktop computers instead of downloaded onto local machine, installed and played. There are plenty of games that work like that built using Unity or Unreal but can Panda3D do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Member of the community called Yonnji confirmed that Panda3D game indeed can be served from a cloud provider: https://discourse.panda3d.org/t/panda3d-running-from-cloud-mobile-game-development/26039/4

Secondly, speaking of deployment to Android. There's a port to Android however as the snippet from official docs say deployment on Android is quite a struggle at the moment but looks like devs are working hard to make it easier for the future.

> Android port
>
> The new release has made significant strides towards bringing the
>   Android port to the level of quality one should expect of a Panda
>   port. It’s now even possible to compile Panda3D on your Android
>   machine, and there is even a third-party development environment
>   available on the Play Store for developing Python games on your
>   Android device. The major shortcoming as of yet is that there is no
>   easy deployment pipeline yet to deploy your games for Android, so that
>   will be a major priority going forward.

Sadly, no mention of support for iOS.

Comment: It doesn't look like they're talking about the same kind of server deployment as you are. You seem to be asking about streaming to a thin client, while they seem to be talking about a conventional headless dedicated server.